# agilityjs view not displaying model value 0

Tags: agility.js

I am using a AgilityJS in my project and I have the following scenario:

```
var obj = $$({some_model_prop: val_from_server},'<div></div>'});
body.append(obj);
```

Here body is another agility object containing the main page's body view.

The problem is if the value of val_from server happens to be 0(zero number) it is not displayed inside the div although the div is rendered.

If I convert the val_from_server to string by appending quotes("") to it it shows up but then I have to convert the string to number while fetching it later from the model.

Is there something that I am doing wrrong.. or is it a bug in agility itself.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in Agility itself; looks like [it was just fixed a couple of days ago](https://github.com/arturadib/agility/issues/105).  Dunno how long it will take for the change to propagate into the official minified version linked at `http://agilityjs.com/docs/agility.min.js`, but you can pull a working version directly from GitHub at `https://github.com/arturadib/agility/blob/master/agility.js`.